# Como fazer substituições em strings a partir de índices de tuplas em larga escala?

Tags: python, string

Preciso encontrar o índice de algumas palavras em uma string, armazenar esses índices e, a partir deles, realizar outras substituições baseadas em índices de tuplas, que sinalizam quais palavras devem ser substituídas e onde estão (índice) na string. É necessário ter o índice porque é preciso detectar em que ponto do texto pode ser aplicada a operação reversa futuramente, já que nem toda palavra está na ortografia não oficial. Por exemplo, nem todo "ela" está registrada como "ea", nem todo "com" como "c'", etc. Por isso, substituições sem registrar o índice não resolvem meu problema. A proposta é transformar ortografia não oficial na oficial. Até agora, já encontrei os índices das substituições a serem feitas, mas não sei substituir em larga escala.  A string de exemplo é a seguinte:

```
texto = """
ontem ea foi lá cum uma cara fea demais
e' falou c'ocê na parte da tarde
o' como que eu tô tá vendo
  """
```

A partir da string, utilizo uma expressão regular que me dá as seguintes tuplas:

```
tuplas1 = [
    ("ela", "ea"),
    ("com", "cum"),
    ("feia", "fea"),
    ("ele", "e'"),
    ("com você", "c'ocê"),
    ("olha", "o'"),
    ("estou", "tô"),
    ("está", "tá"),
]
```

Para conseguir o índice das palavras da ortografia não oficial na string, utilizo o segundo elemento da variável `tuplas1` como base. Fiz assim:

```
for x, y in enumerate(texto2.split()):
    for z in tuplas1:
        if y == z[1]:
            lista_idx.append((x, y, z[0]))
```

Resultado:

```
lista_idx = [
    (1, "ea", "ela"),
    (4, "cum", "com"),
    (7, "fea", "feia"),
    (9, "e'", "ele"),
    (11, "c'ocê", "com você"),
    (16, "o'", "olha"),
    (20, "tô", "estou"),
    (21, "tá", "está"),
]
```

Agora preciso usar o terceiro elemento de cada tupla em `lista_idx` para substituir o segundo elemento da tupla baseado no índice, dado no primeiro elemento. No exemplo abaixo, transformei a string em lista e substituí o elemento de índice `[1]` de `texto_lista` pelo elemento de índice `[2]` da tupla de índice `[0]`, isto é, substituí "ea" por "ela" na primeira tupla da variável `lista_idx`:

```
lista_idx = [(1, 'ea', 'ela')
texto_lista = texto.split()
texto_lista[1] = lista_idx[1][2]
```

Resultado de exemplo: a frase ''ontem ea foi lá cum uma cara fea demais'' ficaria "ontem ela foi lá com uma cara feia demais".
Como fazer isso baseado em todos os índices armazenados no primeiro elemento da variável `lista_idx` no texto?

Comment: Qual deveria ser o resultado? Se vc só quer usar as tuplas para substituir na string original, bastaria isso: https://ideone.com/Ml40nF

Comment: Obrigado por tentar ajudar. É necessário ter o índice porque é preciso detectar em que ponto do texto pode ser aplicada a operação reversa futuramente, já que nem toda palavra está na ortografia não oficial. Por exemplo, nem todo "ela" está registrada como "ea", nem todo "com" como "c'", etc. Editei meu post com essa informação. Infelizmente, o replace não resolve. Resultado de exemplo: a frase ''ontem ea foi lá cum uma cara fea demais'' ficaria "ontem ela foi lá com uma cara feia demais".

Comment: Não sei se entendi, mas enfim, outra alternativa: https://ideone.com/0mzauf

Comment: Vc quer substituir palavras baseada na posição das mesmas?

Comment: É isso mesmo @hkotsubo . Consegui fazer no for loop de forma  diferente. Transformei o texto todo em lista e fiz assim "for x in lista_idx: texto_lista[x[0]] = x[2]". Dessa forma, o texto em lista recebe, na posição de x[0], o terceiro elemento da tupla. Aí é só juntar com join. De qualquer forma, obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @PauloMarques Queria substituir a segunda palavra da tupla (1, "ea", "ela") no texto que passei. Coloquei o texto em lista e fiz for loop na lista de tuplas: "for x in lista_idx: texto_lista[x[0]] = x[2]", de forma que o texto em lista recebe, na posição x[0], o terceiro elemento da tupla x[2]. Ideia bastante complexa por trás e código muito simples de se fazer, mas quebrei a cabeça por uns dois dias.

Answer (score 0):

Já consegui, pessoal. Usei o princípio de substituição individual `texto_lista[1] = lista_idx[1][2]` como na pergunta, mas dentro do loop for, sem indicar o índice de ordem da tupla, já que seriam todas. Nesse caso, indico apenas `x2`, pra indicar o terceiro elemento. Assim eu substituo todas as palavras da ortografia não oficial, na posição `x1` pelas da ortografia oficial, na posição `x2`

`texto_lista = texto.split()`

`for x in lista_idx: texto_lista[x[0]] = x[2]`

`print (texto_lista) ['ontem', 'ela', 'foi', 'lá', 'com', 'uma', 'cara', 'feia', 'demais', 'ele', 'falou', 'com você', 'na', 'parte', 'da', 'tarde', 'olha', 'como', 'que', 'eu', 'estou', 'está', 'vendo']`

Posteriormente, é só transformar em string com `" ".join.`

`" ".join(texto_lista) Out[30]: 'ontem ela foi lá com uma cara feia demais ele falou com você na parte da tarde olha como que eu estou está vendo'`